# c# code to get Selected query result in a array

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I wanted to get the SQL Select query result in a array or when reading a results i wanted to do an update or insertion in a table... Please Someone help me. My code is below

```
    private void updateNewTask()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        GetCurrentDate();
        DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        string UserDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()).TotalMinutes).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:SS");
        string sql = "SELECT Recurring_Id FROM Master_Recurring where Recurring_Id Not in" +
                " (SELECT Recurring_Id FROM Master_Recurring WHERE Last_Completed < '" + lblServerDate + "' ANd Recurring_Active='True')";     
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Recurrid = reader["Recurring_Id"].ToString();
                GetRecurringDetails();                                     
            }
            connection.Close();


        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }

    private void GetRecurringDetails()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sql = "select * from Master_Recurring where Recurring_Id='" + Recurrid + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Empcode = reader["Emp_Code"].ToString();
                TaskTitle = reader["Task_Title"].ToString();
                TaskMsg = reader["Task_Message"].ToString();
                TaskPriority = reader["Task_Priority"].ToString();
                TaskLogincode = reader["Task_Login_code"].ToString();
                TaskLoginName = reader["Task_Login_name"].ToString();
                Recurringcount = reader["Recurring_Count"].ToString();
                Totcount = reader["Total_Count"].ToString();                            
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Here am Getting Connection open error...

Comment: Please post **exact error message** and which line you got it at.

Comment: Please use parametrized queries, this code opens you up too sql injection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Comment: Your `connection` is defined somewhere else so there's no way for us to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: When am Executing the line Connection.open() in GetRecurringDetails()... it throws me error as connection is open

Comment: Where is your connection string? Post the code where you are creating object of sqlconnection class.

Comment: i have defined connection string in the starting of the page

Comment: And where exactly your page is? We need to see it to pin point the problem.

Comment: @user3331850 If the message says the connection is already open when you try to open it what are you actually asking us to help with? Surely the message is clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check connection state before opening the connection again.

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
     connection.Open();
}
```

Comment: thanks. i have corrected

Answer (score 0):

`connection.Open();` is being called twice, the 'updateNewTask' method calls 'GetRecurringDetails();' which calls `connection.Open();` again.

Comment: But at the end of both function he is calling connection.close()

Comment: See the while loop in updateNewTask, he calls the method before he calls close in either of them